# React-Hook-Form conditional fields in a map function

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm curious if anyone has used conditional fields in react-hook-from but within a map function. I've got the basic rendering happening, but since it is in a list and they all refer to the same .map() criteria, it is populating the conditional input for all fields, regardless if they are checked. Heres the basic idea for using conditional fields in RHF: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-conditional-fields-qgr41

Heres what I've got so far:

```
{goals && goals.map((goal) => (
          <>
          <FormControlLabel
            control={
            <Switch
              key={goal.title}
              //id..? marked? title?
              {...register('marked')}
              name='marked'
              value={goal.marked}
            />}
            label={goal.title}
          />
            <br />
            {marked && (
              <>
              <Input
                
                key={goal.title}
                {...register('goal.note')}
                id="note"
                type='text'
                label="Progress Note"
                name="note"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  e.target.value = e.target.value
                }}
              />
              <br />
              </>
            ) }
```

The problem is that from the UI side, when I toggle the switch (or mark a checkbox), that all the fields populated in the map are referring to the same prop in the switch, 'marked'. So when toggling for 1, it populates the additional input field for all elements in the map function.

An additional issue I have yet to look into is passing the data for the individual fields to the data collected by the form for the submit. Right now, my assumption is that all fields would be treated as one value, since the form is recognizing them all together. So ideally if one item in the map is toggled and additional info is provided, then only those values are passed to the form for the submit, rather than all fields (toggled or not) being passed.

**UPDATE**
So I got the toggle functioning by creating a child component in order to more easily manage the state of the toggle, and leveraging the index within the props so the browser would not treat each conditional field as the same:

parent component:

```
 {goals && goals.map((goal, index) => (
          <GoalInput 
            goal={goal} 
            index={index} 
            register={register} 
            control={control}
            errors={errors}
          />
```

new child component:

```
function GoalInput({ goal, index, register, control, errors }) {
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)

    return (
        <>
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Switch
              key={index}
              {...register(`goals.${index}.marked`)}
              checked={toggle}
              name={`goals.${index}.marked`}
              value={toggle}
              onChange={() => setToggle(!toggle)}
            />
          }
          label={goal.title}
        />
          <br />
          {toggle ? (
            <>
            <Controller
              control={control}
              name={`goals.${index}.note`}
              id={`goals.${index}.note`}
              render={({field}) => (
                <Input
                    type='text'
                    index={index}
                    error={!!errors.note}
                    value={field.value}
                    onChange={(e)=>field.onChange(e)}
                    label="Progress Note"
                />
              )}
            />
            <br />
            </>
           
          ) : <></>}
        </>
    )
}
```

So the toggles work independently, appropriately record whether the value of the toggle is true/false, and the subsquent conditional input in being tracked as well. Still have some struggles with the data being passed correctly through to the backend, but that is another issue. Hope this helps anyone coming along.

Comment: is your problem : the problem is when I submit the data I get "moreDetail": true if it's checked or "moreDetail": false if it not . and also after submitting the data and I left a field empty for example Email field I get "email": "" I want only to send the data that are filled if not I want just to skip it ?

Comment: I updated the post to clarify. The main concern is toggling only select fields in the map, rather than all, but the form is watching the check box field (or MUI switch in this case) and populating the additional fields for all items in the map list.